# IL Emit - set an existing property with a boolean value before notifypropertychanged

Tags: c#, poco, inotifypropertychanged, cil, reflection.emit

I'm implementing an emitted propertychanged handler for my POCO object containing virtual auto-properties, and I've got code that works to the point where propertychanged is being raised whenever I change the underlying property. The reason for doing this is that I am sharing a POCO object with the server (for better or for worse), where I will be sending modified objects to the server. I cannot decorate the POCO object with attributes (since the server would also have these decorators, as we share the common class) and I cannot use third-party tools such as Fody or PostSharp due to policies. I need to track whether the object has been modified, and I'm stuck on this.

Here is the Emit that wraps my virtual auto-properties with change notification:

```
    MethodBuilder setMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(setMethod.Name, setMethod.Attributes, setMethod.ReturnType, types.ToArray());
    typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(setMethodBuilder, setMethod);
    ILGenerator wrapper = setMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    ...Emit if property <> value IsModified=true here...

    wrapper.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    wrapper.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    wrapper.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, setMethod, null);
```

What I need to do is get the *set* method of the existing "IsModified" boolean property and set it if the property value <> value.

Here's an example of what I'd like to emit (this is currently defined as a POCO with virtual auto-properties):

```
public class AnEntity
{
    string _myData;
    public string MyData
    {
        get
        {
            return _myData;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_myData <> value) 
            {
                IsModified = true;
                _myData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyData");                
            }
        }
    }

    bool _isModified;
    public bool IsModified { get; set; }
    {
        get
        {
            return _isModified;
        }
        set
        {
            _isModified = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsModified");
        }
    }
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a while...I have managed to create a new property called "NewIsModified" in the new proxy class that was created, however, I'd very much like to reuse the existing IsModified property in my original POCO.

I hope I've explained my question properly and is easy to understand. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I hope it will help someone else, too.

Kind regards.

Comment: mono cecil is an acceptable solution for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working code for do it in Mono.Cecil

C# code before:

```
public class AnEntityVirtual
{
    public virtual string MyData { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsModified { get; set; }
}
```

IL code of the `set_MyData` before:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldarg.1
IL_0002: stfld string ClassLibrary1.AnEntityVirtual::'<MyData>k__BackingField'
IL_0007: ret
```

The rewriting:

```
// Read the module and get the relevant type
var assemblyPath = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\ClassLibrary1.dll";
var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(assemblyPath);
var type = module.Types.Single(t => t.Name == "AnEntityVirtual");

// Get the method to rewrite
var myDataProperty = type.Properties.Single(prop => prop.Name == "MyData");
var isModifiedSetMethod = type.Properties.Single(prop => prop.Name == "IsModified").SetMethod;
var setMethodBody = myDataProperty.SetMethod.Body;

// Initilize before rewriting (clear pre instructions, create locals and init them)
setMethodBody.Instructions.Clear();
var localDef = new VariableDefinition(module.TypeSystem.Boolean);
setMethodBody.Variables.Add(localDef);
setMethodBody.InitLocals = true;

 // Get fields\methos to use in the new method body
 var propBackingField = type.Fields.Single(field => field.Name == $"<{myDataProperty.Name}>k__BackingField");
var equalMethod =
            myDataProperty.PropertyType.Resolve().Methods.FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name == "Equals") ??
            module.ImportReference(typeof(object)).Resolve().Methods.Single(method => method.Name == "Equales");
var equalMethodReference = module.ImportReference(equalMethod);

// Start the rewriting
var ilProcessor = setMethodBody.GetILProcessor();

// First emit a Ret instruction. This is beacause we want a label to jump if the values are equals
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var ret = setMethodBody.Instructions.First();

ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)); // load 'this'
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldfld, propBackingField)); // load backing field
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_1)); // load 'value'
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(equalMethod.IsStatic ? OpCodes.Call : OpCodes.Callvirt, equalMethodReference)); // call equals
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Stloc_0)); // store result
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc_0)); // load result
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, ret)); // check result and jump to Ret if are equals
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)); // load 'this'
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1)); // load 1 ('true')
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Call, isModifiedSetMethod)); // set IsModified to 'true'
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)); // load this
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_1)); // load 'value'
ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ret, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Stfld, propBackingField)); // store 'value' in backing field
// here you can call to Notify or whatever you want
module.Write(assemblyPath.Replace(".dll", "_new") + ".dll"); // save the new assembly
```

C# code after:

```
public virtual string MyData
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return this.<MyData>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        if (!this.<MyData>k__BackingField.Equals(value))
        {
            this.IsModified = true;
            this.<MyData>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

IL code after:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldfld string ClassLibrary1.AnEntityVirtual::'<MyData>k__BackingField'
IL_0006: ldarg.1
IL_0007: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.String::Equals(object)
IL_000c: stloc.0
IL_000d: ldloc.0
IL_000e: brtrue.s IL_001e

IL_0010: ldarg.0
IL_0011: ldc.i4.1
IL_0012: call instance void ClassLibrary1.AnEntityVirtual::set_IsModified(bool)
IL_0017: ldarg.0
IL_0018: ldarg.1
IL_0019: stfld string ClassLibrary1.AnEntityVirtual::'<MyData>k__BackingField'

IL_001e: ret
```

As I wrote, this is an example of how to do it in Cecil. 
In your real code, you can base on that, but with some changes.

For example, you can create private field for your property and not use the compiler generated backing field.

You may call OptimizeMacros.

Also if you know exactly which property you need to rewrite, you can call to other equal method, e.g. if it's `string`, you can call a static method of type string `op_Equality` or `op?_Inequality` this is the `==` and `!=` of `string`

Comment: Thank you very much, Dudi. Unfortunately, I cannot use Mono.Cecil, as we have very limited internal policy constraints. I also don't know the name of any properties of a type, except for isModifed until runtime, as a new proxy is created based on types <T>, though the proxy type created will always contain isModified. I'll take your approach and try to make it work with IL Emit.

Comment: @option You welcome. For unknown properties name its the same. Just enumerate type.Properties. Its not hard to implement it with Reflection.Emit, same principle. If you need me to do that maybe I could tomorrow morning.

Comment: thank very much you for offering - I have that part all working where I'm looping through the properties and adding the notifypropertychanged event to them...it's just the isModified part left to do:
    public string MyData
    {
    ... set
        {
            if(_myData <> value) 
            {
                IsModified = true;
                _myData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyData");                
            }
        }
    }

Comment: thanks for your answer - I've managed to set the internal IsModified field with your approach by getting:
var isModifiedSetMethod = type.GetProperty("IsModified").SetMethod;
...then passing this to the method that wraps the property setter:

            setMethodWrapperIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setMethodWrapperIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
            setMethodWrapperIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, prop); // store into IsModified

Comment: @Option You welcome. If it works, you can add your solution as answer. If my answer is good enough, you can accept my answer:)

Comment: thank you, I marked your answer as the answer...for anyone else out there stuck, here is how I got a reference to the property in my POCO:
MethodInfo isModifiedSetMethod = type.GetProperty("IsModified").SetMethod;